# Can a Binance SmartChain / BSC full node be run on Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, bsc, binance

If Geth is available on Windows, shouldn't that mean it's doable, or am I misunderstanding how it works?  I was under the impression that Geth *is* essentially the node software. Is that not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the impression that Geth is essentially the node software. Is that not so?

It's one of the client implementations, yes. (There are other Ethereum client implementations that adhere to the spec, listed [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#clients). As far as I know there's only one implementation for BSC... which is the one controlled by Binance.)

> If Geth is available on Windows, shouldn't that mean it's doable

Should be, according to the [installation instructions](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc#building-the-source) in the [BSC GitHub repository](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc). (And yes, they link to the main Ethereum Geth instructions, which includes a set for Windows.)